# Navigation Bar Appearance

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I am using the appearance protocol to change the appearance of all navigation bars in my application, and it works perfectly.

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[ApplicationStyle navigationBarImage] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

I do not want the navigation bar to change on the UIImagePickerController, but I want a clean way to accomplish this, any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[[UINavigationBar appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UIImagePickerController class], nil] setBackgroundImage:nil forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];`